# MVC .NET site inks not pointing correctly to the base URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have developed and tested a site on an IIS server at an IP address. Everything was and is working perfectly if I use the IP address in the URL. However for production, the client wanted a friendly domain URL. In other words https://www.IPAddress.com is supposed to point to my default MVC login page at https://www.example.com/department/Account/Login. The client's network team set it all up and most of the links work fine.

However, in some other places the "/department" is not getting appended to the URL, and the link goes to https://www.example.com/Action/Controller (instead of https:www.example.com/department/Action/Controller).

What I discovered so far is that @Html.ActionLinks in Views are pointing correctly.

So this works: @Html.ActionLink("Create a login!", "Register"). 
It correctly points to the URL https://www.example.com/department/Account/Register.

But this does not (in controller code):

```
                if (await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id.ToString(), "Admin"))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Admin"
                                );
                        }
                if (await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user.Id.ToString(), "User"))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "User");
                        }
```

The code posts incorrectlyto https://www.example.com/Admin/Dashboard, instead of https://www.example.com/department/Admin/Dashboard

Does this have to do with something the network folks have not done. Or is there a place I can set the base URL in my webconfig file?

Thanks in advance,

Sanjeev

Comment: Are you using MVC areas?

Comment: No just a regular MVC 5 app. No areas.

Comment: Can you provide your RouteConfig?

Comment: This is my Route.config
 
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                //defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}